# "Can't open display" even after access with xhost

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a graphical program remotely, without using ssh. I've set the display variable on the server (let's say **server.com**, Linux, not ubuntu, and no su rights) to point to my workstation (**workstation.com**, ubuntu 10.04)

```
setenv DISPLAY workstation.com:0
```

Then on my workstation I've tried both

```
xhost +server.com
```

and

```
xhost +
```

Then I ssh into the server (to test things):

```
ssh username@server.com
```

and try to run `xclock`, and get the following error:

```
Error: Can't open display: workstation.com:0
```

I've looked at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the workstation and I should be forwarding correctly: `X11Forwarding yes`.

**How do I go about troubleshooting this?**

**What logs on the workstation document these failed attempts?**

To explain why I'm doing this: I want to run a batch job on a server to debug an MPI-based parallel program. I want to run xterm as the batch job executable, per the instructions provided by the system admins.

This setup use to work. I reinstalled things on my workstation and since then I frequently get one-time message along the lines `The authenticity of host 'hostname (XXX.XXX.XXX.XX)' can't be established.`

My attempt to fix the above was to move my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to a back up on both server and host, and then to `ssh` from each to the other with the flag `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. I no longer get that message, but I was wondering does this play a part in why X11 forwarding is not working?

Comment: I was going to tag this with `xhost` but I don't have enough reputation to create the tag, so please feel free to adjust the tags as you see fit.

Comment: Is this question `ubuntu` enough, or should it be moved to unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a firewall issue. TCP (port 6000) was being blocked, always, and no matter what I did with xhost, XAuthority, etc. the forwarding was not happening.

I adjusted the firewall settings using the utility `Firewall Configuration`, found in the `System > Administration` menu.

Comment: how do you do this in terminal?

Comment: @user1872384 I'm not sure, I would ask a new question and you'll get more help that way.

Comment: I've managed to solved it. Mine is not cause by this.. Thank you so much Yann. I just need to use -X when ssh to my server.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue on the remote server. Try the following:

1. Add the following to your `sshd_config`:

   ```
   AddressFamily inet
   ```
2. Restart SSH

(Ref: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/cant-open-display-882197/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me, also after trying the `xhost +` method, NOT via ssh X forwarding:

Add to /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

which should cause GDM to start the Xserver without the -nolisten tcp flag in Ubuntu.

Then, `sudo service gdm restart`

Answer (score 1):

Since 11.10 (Oneiric), it is using LightDM instead of GDM. You'll need to modify /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

under [SeatDefaults], add:

```
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

then reboot (recommended) or `sudo service lightdm restart` which may lose your working desktop session.