# "xhost +" produce access control disabled message but do not works

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, 19.10

When under kubuntu enter command `xhost +` I got answer:

> access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

But when try running X application under different user (su - username) I  got answer:

> Error: Can't open display:

Connected link:
["Can't open display" even after access with xhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141240/cant-open-display-even-after-access-with-xhost)

**EDIT**

Yes, $DISPLAY was empty. I obviously get used that it is always set correctly. Thanks Arjen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-applications try to connect to the X-server that is referred to in the environment variable DISPLAY. Enter `echo $DISPLAY` to show its current value. It should look like `:0` or `localhost:0`.

When starting the `su`-shell with `su - username`, all environment variables will be cleared. This is a security measure.

You can start the X application in su-mode with `DISPLAY=:0 xapplication` (substitute `:0` with the value that was shown with the `echo` command).